# validating a form dynamically built in flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a problem sending data in a form, which will not be the case. In the view, I build a dynamically form of agreement has some more complex models in the code is much simpler but the idea is the same.
When I complete the form, this is never processed. I really do not know what may be the problem.

code:

```
from wtforms import StringField,SubmitField
from flask.ext.wtf import Form

@preguntas.route('/pregunta/encuesta/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def view():
    class F(Form):
         pass

    #building form
    setattr(F,'funcion1', StringField(label='fun1'))
    setattr(F,'funcion2', StringField(label='fun2'))
    setattr(F,'enviar', SubmitField('enviar formulario'))

    formulario = F()

    if formulario.validate_on_submit():
        #never comes to this part of the code
        print "saving data..."


    return render_template('pregunta/page.html',form = formulario)
```

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few things you need to check. What is it in the form that you are trying to validate? In you code sample I don't see the use of validator. for example,

```
setattr(F,'funcion1', StringField(label='fun1', [validators.Length(max=10)]))
```

This should add a validators that validate that no more than 10 characters were entered. You can add to the list of validators any validator you would like

In addition if you are using CSRF protection and POST you should include the {{hidden_tag}}`or`{{formulario.csrf_token}}` as the first element in your form 
your form in your template should look like this:

```
<form action="{{url_for('some_view'}}">
{{hidden_tag}}
<!-- rest of form elements --> 
</form>
```

And try to see what errors you get from your forms bu doing this:

```
formulario = F()
print formulario.errors
if formulario.validate_on_submit():
    # some code
```

Comment: I refer to the processing of the request form, and not the validation of a field of the form. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: try to print form.errors before the validation and see what errors you get. I suspect that you are not using a CSRF token and that is causing `validate_on_submit()` to return false. `print form.errors` should verify that. If this is the case then at the top of your form in your template, 
add  `{{ formulario.csrf_token }}`

Comment: just to correct my comment instead of `print form.errors` use `print formulario.errors`